# Can you Add The Digits in a Two Digit Number Together Without First Converting it to a String?

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript, is there a way to add the digits of a two digit number together without first converting it to a string?

For example, I want to take the number 15 and add the two numbers it's composed of together to get 6. Now, usually I'd go about doing something like this:

```
var myNum = 15,
    numString = myNum.toString(),
    firstNum = +numString[0],
    secondNum = +numString[1];

alert(firstNum + secondNum);
```

How can I accomplish this same result without converting the number to a string at the beginning? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
> 15 % 10 + Math.floor(15 / 10)
6
```

Or recursively:

```
function sumDigits(n) {
  return n % 10 + (n > 0 ? sumDigits(Math.floor(n / 10)) : 0);
}
```

```
> sumDigits(123)
6
```

Comment: Brilliant answer. Out of curiosity, is there a way to scale this pattern to numbers beyond two digits?